# Databases and B+Trees indexes

Tags: sql, indexing, b-tree, database-indexes, b-tree-index

Where can I find information on whether which databases are using B+Trees over B-Trees for their index implementations?

Oracle appears to be using B+Trees. Although they don't describe it on their documentation, their [graphics](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_9i_indexing.htm) appear to be pointing that B+Trees are actually being used.

Comment: Your tag binary-trees should not be confused with BxTrees

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia lists [a number of databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B-tree) which support B+ trees.

Note, however, that it is entirely possible for a database to support multiple kinds of indexes

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server the info is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx

In SQL Server, indexes are organized as B-trees. Each page in an index B-tree is called an index node. The top node of the B-tree is called the root node. The bottom level of nodes in the index is called the leaf nodes. Any index levels between the root and the leaf nodes are collectively known as intermediate levels. In a clustered index, the leaf nodes contain the data pages of the underlying table. The root and intermediate level nodes contain index pages holding index rows. Each index row contains a key value and a pointer to either an intermediate level page in the B-tree, or a data row in the leaf level of the index. The pages in each level of the index are linked in a doubly-linked list.

Comment: This seems like a specialized version closer to the B+tree?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's default index is a B* index. (A B* index is "any" variation of a B+ index.) Oracle mentions B* in some of their DBA and Fundamentals documentation. You can also create clusters which use cluster indexes. You can create bitmap indexes in a data warehouse or OLAP database. Bitmap indexes perform extremly poorly in an OLTP database although they might work ok if a table is rarely updated.

For performance reasons, I'm sure that all databases designed for OLTP use B* trees as their primary indexes. Teradata, for example, is designed for data warehousing and uses hash-based indexes.